# Flutter arkit_plugin 0.6.0 pods fail to install

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality

I am trying to use arkit_plugin 0.6.0 and pods fail to install. Pods fail because "'ARWorldTrackingConfiguration' is only available in iOS 11.0". I need to update my AppDelegate.swift file in order for plugin to work. Below is my Podfile. How do I fix this?

## Podfile

```
platform :ios, '12.0'
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
      config.build_settings['DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT'] = 'dwarf'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'
      config.build_settings['OTHER_SWIFT_FLAGS'] = '-DDISABLE_TRUEDEPTH_API'
  end
end
end
```

Comment: try changing this line `config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '9.0'`

Comment: If that doesn't help, try changing your minimum target in XCode

Comment: Will try to change to config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '11.0'.

Comment: Its working now and this post can be closed. Thanks for fast reply.